# JavaScript - Restart setTimeout timer in a recursive function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to make an automatic slideshow in css and js. I've got a function that infinitely loops through an array of images (in the slideshow) after a specified time.

```
function autoSlide(){
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

    t = setTimeout("autoSlide()", time);
}
```

But I want to reset the timer `time` if I manually change the slide by pressing a button. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
function autoSlide(){
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

    nextBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        clearTimeout(t);
    })

    t = setTimeout("autoSlide()", time);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's the time you want to reset rather than the counter? Is `time` incrementing over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.
Like this:

```
function autoSlide(){
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
}
var t = setInterval(autoSlide, time)
nextBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    clearInterval(t);
    t= setInterval(autoSlide, time)
})
```

Comment: this would stop the timer for ever. the goal is to restart the timer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you're defining the interval variable outside of the function scope so it might be getting lost. Also, shouldn't this be a `setInterval` vs `setTimeout`? You could use either, but if your goal is to infinitely repeat until some condition, `setInterval` is more appropriate

```
let interval = setInterval(autoSlide, time); // variable being initialized outside function scope
nextBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(autoSlide, time)
})
function autoSlide(){
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    // ... presumably other logic to progress your slideshow every 'time'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to recreate the timer when you click. Not only delete the timer, but also recreate it.

```
nextBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(autoSlide, time);
})
```

ps: it's always good to learn, but dont try too much to reinvent the wheel.
use this for exemple : https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html
responseive, auto, touch support, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If this is a carousel you want your timeout to be the same but to reset the counter when you click the button.

Here's a function that sets up your timer, and your button, and returns a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (a function that retains the information in its preceding lexical environment after it's been returned) that controls the timeout.

```js
function handler() {

  const time = 1000;
  let counter = 0;

  const button = document.addEventListener('click', () => counter = 0);

  return function loop() {

    // Your transform code goes here
    console.log(counter);
    counter++;
    setTimeout(loop, time);
  }

}

// autoSlide is the returned function
const autoSlide = handler();
autoSlide();
```

```html
<button>Stop the sliding!</button>
```